# Place span inside div on bottom

Tags: html, css

folks!

there is a problem layouting my page header :/

i want to place the logo and title on the left, and some usermenu/logout/messages on the right.

html:

```
<div class="banner">
  <img class="logo" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODdhMgAyAPQAAL7ikLjfh+r12q3adNTstfr99u/45OTz0fT67c7prMPkmbPdftnuv8nno9/wyP///6jYawAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACwAAAAAMgAyAAAF5iAkjmRpnmiqrmzrvnAsz3Rt33iu73zv/8CgcEgsGo/IpHLJvAUGvIBK8Kg+AJAAtUCIAaxVUQLxEGBPgi7JcMg+GrBvKfBQQBgFVLpUFxnUIwYGAwMIbSRyJAkPIl9SJlQPXCJXIgICJQsFDgeDJV9VCFIEmBADlSZPAwwPUqiXJl8FjyQDUgEGmKQip2cplX0Qf7GStCcEjIuNrScNUMhSbG5wJJqkCFCIWAMCbXR2eChgalqSgIGYAwWHI4uhj2MPBnYnAwAAC3PZMQv3qU0AAwocSLCgwYMIEypcyLChw4cQl4QAADs=">
  <div class="title">foo</div>
  <div class="logout">bar</div>
</div>
<div class="content">
Some Content..
</div>
```

css:

```
.banner {
height: 50px;
background-color: #feefef;
}
.img, .title, .logout{
vertical-align: text-bottom;
height:100%;
}
.logo {float: left;}
.title {float:left;}
.logout {float:right;}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/z9gervtm/3/

How do i move those texts to the bottom?

Comment: So you want the items aligned to the bottom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use flexbox and get rid of the floats. Add divs to have a left and right banner section. Align-items center to make it look nice:

```css
.banner {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  background-color: #feefef;
}

.left {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.right {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.left img,
.right div:first-of-type {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <div class="left">
    <img class="logo" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODdhMgAyAPQAAL7ikLjfh+r12q3adNTstfr99u/45OTz0fT67c7prMPkmbPdftnuv8nno9/wyP///6jYawAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACwAAAAAMgAyAAAF5iAkjmRpnmiqrmzrvnAsz3Rt33iu73zv/8CgcEgsGo/IpHLJvAUGvIBK8Kg+AJAAtUCIAaxVUQLxEGBPgi7JcMg+GrBvKfBQQBgFVLpUFxnUIwYGAwMIbSRyJAkPIl9SJlQPXCJXIgICJQsFDgeDJV9VCFIEmBADlSZPAwwPUqiXJl8FjyQDUgEGmKQip2cplX0Qf7GStCcEjIuNrScNUMhSbG5wJJqkCFCIWAMCbXR2eChgalqSgIGYAwWHI4uhj2MPBnYnAwAAC3PZMQv3qU0AAwocSLCgwYMIEypcyLChw4cQl4QAADs=">
    <div class="title">Title</div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="logout">Logout</div>
    <div class="messages">Messages</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="content">
  Some Content..
</div>
```

Comment: i also like your advanced solution with multiple elemnts on the right

Comment: @MegaChroniX you have asked for items aligned at the bottom `How do i move those texts to the bottom?`, this answer doesn't do that. Next time be more specific about what you want. This answer is a copy of mine, answered 5 minutes later, even copy the new elements parent's classes name `left`

Comment: @dippas you think bc I came up with left and right for class names that I copied your answer? Nice assumption but don't make me laugh. This is standard flexbox. I must have been coding it while you posted your answer so get off your high horse.  And why wouldn't someone want their nav items vertically centered? All standard

Answer (score 2):

use flexbox to simplify your code

```css
.banner {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #feefef;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-end
}

.left {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <div class="left">
    <img class="logo" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODdhMgAyAPQAAL7ikLjfh+r12q3adNTstfr99u/45OTz0fT67c7prMPkmbPdftnuv8nno9/wyP///6jYawAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACwAAAAAMgAyAAAF5iAkjmRpnmiqrmzrvnAsz3Rt33iu73zv/8CgcEgsGo/IpHLJvAUGvIBK8Kg+AJAAtUCIAaxVUQLxEGBPgi7JcMg+GrBvKfBQQBgFVLpUFxnUIwYGAwMIbSRyJAkPIl9SJlQPXCJXIgICJQsFDgeDJV9VCFIEmBADlSZPAwwPUqiXJl8FjyQDUgEGmKQip2cplX0Qf7GStCcEjIuNrScNUMhSbG5wJJqkCFCIWAMCbXR2eChgalqSgIGYAwWHI4uhj2MPBnYnAwAAC3PZMQv3qU0AAwocSLCgwYMIEypcyLChw4cQl4QAADs=">
    <div class="title">foo</div>
  </div>
  <div class="logout">bar</div>
</div>
<div class="content">
  Some Content..
</div>
```